# Finding the characteristic polynomial of $B$ given $B^2$ is a non-negative definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find the characteristic polynomial of $B$ such that $B^2=\left[\begin{array}{cc}5&-3\\-3&5\end{array}\right]$. One can find the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix and show that the roots are $2$ and $8$, so that we know the eigenvalues of $B^2$ are $2$ and $8$. But that only implies that eigenvalues of $B$ can be any two of the 4 values $\pm\sqrt{2},\pm\sqrt{8}$. So how can one determine the exact characteristic polynomial of $B$?

Comment: Such $B$ is not unique. For example, $B$ and $-B$. Thus any $B$ whose characteristic polynomial has roots $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\pm \sqrt{8}$ is suffice. Thus overall there will be 4 choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four matrices satisfy

$${B}^{2} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}5&{-3}\\
{-3}&5
\end{array}\right]$$

they are

$$B = \pm  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}{-3}&1\\
1&{-3}
\end{array}\right] \quad  \text{or} \quad  B = \pm  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&{-3}\\
{-3}&1
\end{array}\right]$$

There are also four characteristic polynomials

$$\det  \left(t I-B\right) = {t}^{2} \pm  3 \sqrt{2} t+4 \quad  \text{or} \quad  \det  \left(t I-B\right) = {t}^{2} \pm  \sqrt{2} t-4$$

This can be obtained by solving directly

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}5&{-3}\\
{-3}&5
\end{array}\right] = {\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}\right]}^{2} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}{a}^{2}+b c&b \left(a+d\right)\\
c \left(a+d\right)&{d}^{2}+b c
\end{array}\right]$$

This implies ${a}^{2} = {d}^{2}$ and $a+d \neq  0$, hence
$a = d$ and $b = c$. It remains ${a}^{2}+{b}^{2} = 5$
and $2 a b =-3$. It follows that ${\left(a+b\right)}^{2} = 2$
and ${\left(a-b\right)}^{2} = 8$, hence $a+b = {\varepsilon} \sqrt{2}$
and $a-b = 2{{\varepsilon}'} \sqrt{2}$ with ${\varepsilon} = \pm  1$
and ${{\varepsilon}'} = \pm  1$. Hence

$$a = d = \left({\varepsilon}+2 {{\varepsilon}'}\right) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \quad  \text{and} \quad  b = c = \left({\varepsilon}-2 {{\varepsilon}'}\right) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$